# Checking whether total derivative is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces

I would like to know whether my total derivative $dF : U \to L(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open, is bounded. For $(x,y) \in U$, the matrix for $dF$ is given by
$$ dF(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -2 \sin x & 0 \end{pmatrix} . $$
I'm slightly confused about what the meaning of $dF$ bounded is here. If I use single variable functions as intuition, then I'd take it to mean that there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $||dF(x,y)|| \leq M$ for all $(x,y) \in U$.

So let's try to check this. Pick an arbitrary $(x,y) \in U$. Now I'll use the operator norm to evaluate $||dF(x,y)||$. We get
$$ ||dF(x,y)|| = \sup \{  ||dF(x,y)(u,v)||_2 \mid (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \, ||(u,v)||_2 = 1 \}  $$
where $||-||_2$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Computing the thing in the supremum, I get
$$ ||dF(x,y)(u,v)||_2 = \sqrt{v^2+4u^2 \sin(x)} \leq \sqrt{4v^2+4u^2} = 2 $$
where I take into account the $||(u,v)||_2 = 1$ condition.

So in conclusion, it seems to me that I have shown that $||dF(x,y)|| \leq 2$ regardless of $(x,y)$, so $dF$ is indeed bounded. Is this the correct reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. Since all spaces are finite-dimensional here, it's clear that $dF(x, y)$ is a bounded linear transformation for each $(x, y)$, so bounded here most likely means $\sup_{(x, y) \in U}\|dF(x, y)\| < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In general a linear operator $L:X \to Y$ is bounded if there exists $M$ such that
$$
||Lx||_Y \le M||x||_X
$$
So you need to show that there exists $C$ such that
$$
||dF(x,y)||_{L(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)} \le C\sqrt{x^2+y^2 }
$$
You can define the operator norm
$$
||dF||:=\inf\{M : ||dF(x,y)||_{L(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)} \le M ||(x,y)|| \text{ for all } (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}= \sup_{||(x,y)||=1} ||dF(x,y)||_{L(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)}
$$
You have
$$
||dF||=\sup_{||(x,y)||=1} \sup_{||(u,v)||=1} ||dF(x,y)(u,v)||_2 \le 2
$$
For what you have shown, so the operator is bounded

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how does what you have written show that $||dF(x,y)||_{L(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)} \le C\sqrt{x^2+y^2 }$?

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 $$\frac{||dF(x,y)||_L}{||(x,y)||} \le \sup_{||(x,y)|| \ne 0}\left\{ \frac{||dF(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||}\right\}=\sup_{||(x,y)||=1} ||dF(x,y)||$$

Comment: Ah, is it because the smallest such $C$ (the optimal bound) is the operator norm of $dF$?

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 Exactly

Comment: I guess I'm asking, is $||dF(x,y)|| \leq ||dF|| ||(x,y)||_2$ true?

Comment: Ok thanks very much!